# Eventhough i have defined a function inside my code, still it's showing "Nameerror: not defined" in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, symbol-table

```
t=int(input("enter no of test cases"))
global mylist1,mylist2

for a in range(t):
    n = int(input("number of cubes"))
    while True:
        list_inp = input("enter list").split()
        if len(list_inp)== n:
            break
        print("no of list items is not equal to specified length.")
    mylist=[int(x) for x in list_inp]                            

    x = min(mylist)             
    y = mylist.index(x)                                     
    mylist1 = mylist[0:x]                                   
    mylist2 = mylist[x:]

    if isascend(mylist2) and isdescend(mylist1):    
        print('yes')                                

    else:
        print('no')





def isdescend(mylist1):                     
    previous = mylist1[0]
    for number in mylist1:
        if number > previous:
            return False
        previous = number
    return True




def isascend(mylist2):      
    previous = mylist2[0]
    for number in mylist2:
        if number < previous:
            return False
        previous = number
    return True
```

> In the if block isascend and is descend are not defined showing "unresolved reference" but why??
>   Why the function cannot be called?Is there some kind of order followed for defining a function in python.
>   how can i resolve this?? I'm new to programming &symbol table concept.

Comment: Where have you defined `isascend`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the functions before the code that uses them.

Comment: yes, i tried that also but its still showing same error. it's only working when i m defining function in the for loop. I think a function should be called from anywhere....i'm missing the underlying concepts ..